# How to force ios perform auto-layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm adding current controller's view into container view. First view's rect is original design rect (320x568), then it's changed to container view frame (320x386). Auto-layout is checked for the controller and xib contains button in vertical-center of the view (blue dash horizontal line in the vertical-center of the view in IB). But after changing of view height (386 instead of 568) button is not in the new center.

How can i force ios to apply constraints?

changing controller:

```
- (void)switchToSection: (NSInteger)selectedIndex {
    [self.indexLabel setText: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"selected segment #%d", selectedIndex]];
    [self.indexLabel sizeToFit];
    self.indexLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.indexLabel.center.y);

    UIViewController *oldViewController =
        _currentSelectedIndex != UISegmentedControlNoSegment
            ? self.controllers[_currentSelectedIndex]
            : NULL;
    UIViewController *newViewController = self.controllers[selectedIndex];
    _currentSelectedIndex = selectedIndex;

    if (oldViewController != NULL)
        [self finishTransitionToOldViewController:oldViewController];

    [self willTransitionToViewController:newViewController]; // settings view.height = container.height
    [self.containerView addSubview:newViewController.view];
    [self didTransitionToViewController:newViewController];
}
```

creating view by controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect viewRect = self.view.frame; // created originally viewRect   CGRect  origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=320, height=568)  
}
```

applying container's rect to child view:

```
- (void)willTransitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    CGRect childRect = self.containerView.bounds;

    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    viewController.view.frame = childRect; // expect iOS to apply constraints

    [viewController.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]; // no luck
    [viewController.view layoutIfNeeded]; // no luck
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` ?

Comment: `[viewController.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` ?

Comment: no `[viewController.view layoutIfNeeded]`

Comment: unfortunately, no luck. i've tried both `layoutIfNeeded ` and `setNeedsUpdateConstraints ` after `viewController.view.autoresizingMask`. i've added comments where rects are set

Comment: updated code with comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first rule of using Auto Layout is that you can never use `someView.frame = blah;`.

You can inspect the frame but you can never set the frame.

Your code is a bit confusing. You say you're using AutoLayout but none of the code you have shown is using Auto Layout.

Just to be clear. Using `autoresizingMask` is not using AutoLayout.

As a guess I'd saying that you have ticked "use Auto Layout" but you haven't actually added any constraints.

Can you show a screen shot of your storyboard with the constraints you have added.

**EDIT**

Ok, I was right.

First off, the blue lines that appear when you drag a view around are not constraints. They are guidelines to help you place things on the screen.

In auto layout you don't define the frame of a view using `CGRectMake(...)` instead you add constraints to the view so that its frame can be inferred... `10 points from the left of the screen` or `button A is 15 points below the bottom of image view B` or `Label X is vertically centred in view Y`.

However, there is a lot more to it than that.

I'd suggest going and starting at the beginning with a tutorial about the very basics of auto layout.

One of my favourite places is [Ray Wenderlich's beginning Auto Layout tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

Comment: button is in view center and it uses 'auto-layout' for positioning. 'Auto-layout' is checked ON for controller. how can i add picture here? btw what does `autoresizingMask ` do?

Comment: added controller view screenshot in IB. ok. what can i use to set new view rect if i can't just use `view.frame = ...`

Comment: @4ntoine could you take a screen shot showing the button selected and on the measurements window in the inspector (the bit that shows the size and position). That will help.

Comment: updated image. i can see no constraints are set, but i can see blue dash line when moving button center vertically.